# Using bots on Facebook groups

Tags: facebook, bots

I am new to Facebook messengers bots. I want to know how can I add a bot to a group (more than 1 people in the conversation). I read about the API in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/complete-guide) 
and I tried some bots like Mealou and getbirdiebot on my messanger. But in order to access them, I had to click on their link, which trigers an event for oppening a private conversation between me and the bot. How can I add a bot to a group then?

Is it even possible?

P.S: In [this link](https://flipboard.com/@flipboard/flip.it%2F-Cghbg-facebook-messenger-adds-group-chat-poll/f-446304668c%2Ftechcrunch.com) facebook uses A.I to read the text and process it in the groups. I want to do something like that.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Messenger Bots are for communication between one user and a page.